# How to save multiple data with same form when multiple user try to update with latest details using asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Problem**
I have a razor view form which is contain more that 100 rows. when a user try to save at a time it is overwriting latest information. Example user A opened form and updated row 1 and 2. At the same time user B also opened form. Both user having latest information and user A updated row 1 and 2 closed the form. Same time user B also updated row 1 and 2 but when user A try to open form his details is overwrited.

How to solve this issues?

Comment: What happens to the data updated by user B? It should not be saved? Are you updating all the 100 rows? Or only the modified rows?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya All the 100 rows i'm updating. whoever user A or user B who is saving latest existing details is overwrited.

Comment: So if user A changes data to `foo` and save and immediately user B changes it to `bar`, the `foo` will be overwritten by `bar`. So the latest data available is `bar`. If this is expected then what's the issue?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya valid question.  User A updated row 1 coulumn 2 and user B updated row 1 coulum 3. When i try to save all the rows and columns i'm taking and updating. Problem is when they open form same time there is no entry then one by one they will save.

Comment: You might want to implement logic which will try to update the only changed rows... But at the same time it is very difficult to check if particular column is already modified by user A.

Comment: You might also want to update only changed rows and columns. That will help you control what changes are being made to the db. This is the approach. For exact solution, can you share details and code around how are updating the data in the database? Also what kind of database you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to achieve. If both users have the right to overwrite the data (at the same time), then this is a valid scenario.

If you don't want this to happen, then you would have to write logic to lock the rows that are selected by the first user.
The second user cannot update the rows until the lock is removed.

Comment: can you share how to lock the rows